# Matlab gives no result when I use the ODE (Ordinary Differential Equations)

Tags: matlab, ode

When trying to find the symbolic solution in the following code, I got nothing (empty sym)!

```
syms y(t) y0 Dy0
Dy = diff(y,t);
func = diff(y,t,2)-(y)^2-4*y==0;
cond1 = y(0) == 1;
cond2 = Dy(1) == 0;
conds = [cond1 cond2];
ySol(t) = dsolve(func,conds);
ySol = simplify(ySol, 'Steps',20)
disp(ySol(t))
```

What was my mistake?
Please advise.

Comment: Do you get any warning?

Comment: I don't see any mistakes on the code It appears your differential equation does not have a solution in terms of elementary functions. I tried to solve it in [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27-y%5E2-4y%3D0) and it gives a rather extensive solution, in terms both of elliptic integrals. Matlab just can't solve it in a "pretty" way. It would be much better for you if you try to solve it numerically.

Comment: Dear Daniel, yes, I got a warning: Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. 
> In dsolve (line 201)
  In symbolic_Fun (line 9) 
 
ySol(t) =
 
[ empty sym ]
 
[ empty sym ]

Comment: Dear Thales. Thank you very much for your reply. Can we use the following boundary conditions in our results?

y(0)=1
y'(1)=0

Comment: Hi. Your problem is discribed in the help for the `dsolve` function. Please, look the link [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dsolve.html) and find the part "When No Solutions Are Found"